# Mysql selects rows from select

Tags: php, mysql

I have one specific problem, I need to make function. User pass sttring into this function. String is MYSQL query and now, I want to change this mysql query as this, if I get for example `SELECT student.name as person FROM student WHERE student.grade = 1 LIMIT 10`  Now i need to create somethink like this `(SELECT student.name as person FROM student WHERE student.grade = 1 LIMIT 10) WHERE person = "John" LIMIT 5` (watch person in where). The Select between ( and ) can be anythink, but my conditions after ) can be only aggregate functions, limit and where conditions. Is somethink like this possible? I need to create it in php. I hope you understand me.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It is a bad idea to let users enter queries.

Comment: You can use Group By person.

Comment: not user as user, but user of my funciton, in this case developer

Comment: you want a function with a parameter `s` that returns `(s) where person = "John...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my initial comment it is a very very bad idea, however you can simply do this:

SELECT * 
FROM ([user supplied query]) AS theQ
WHERE theQ.person = "John"
LIMIT 5;

Once you wrap the user supplied query as a subquery, you can pretty much just use it like a table. Of course, in this case if the user supplied query does not contain a `person` field, the query will error.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it